# Is this Scheme function acceptable?

Tags: scheme, racket

So I am trying to answer a Scheme question which is to, define a function which finds all atoms inside an expression which pass a given predicate i.e

```
(foo number? '(a (2 (c 3) 4)))
=> (2 3 4)
```

or

```
(foo symbol? '(a (2 (c 3) 4)))
=> (a c)
```

I have come up with the following function, which I believe gives the correct output, but I am wondering if this an okay way to do it, or is there a better way?

```
(define (foo predicate expression)
  (cond [(eqv? predicate number?) (filter number? (flatten expression))]
        [(eqv? predicate symbol?) (filter symbol? (flatten expression))]))
```

Comment: *"acceptable"* – by what metrics? SO is intended for more concrete questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see why you don't do:

```
(define (foo predicate expression)
  (filter predicate (flatten expression)))
```

How you have written your function it will only work with two exact ones and not eg:

```
(foo (lambda (v) (or (odd? v) (negative? v))) '(-5 6 8 10 11))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I did originally try to do it the same as yours but it didn't work for me, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong though as I have just tried this and it worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Sylwester's solution. But I think the function is clearer if the data transformation is more explicit. That is, what is getting filtered is not so much the expression as its terms.

```
(define (foo predicate expression)
  (let ((terms (flatten expression))
    (filter predicate terms)))
```

or alternatively

```
(define (foo predicate expression)
  (define terms (flatten expression))
    (filter predicate terms))
```

I find it easier to write functions that way rather than as densely as possible.